# Display the html reports horizontally in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

`I am using JENKINS and i generate the html reports to all my projects, These are displayed in  vertical format.

how can i display the html reports in horizontal format.`

Comment: How are you displaying those reports? Are you using "HTML Publisher Plugin"? Maybe include a screenshot?

Comment: yes, I am using HTML Publisher Plugin